# woocommerce - update order status without sending customer email

Tags: woocommerce

I currently use

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('completed', 'Order has been delivered.');
```

to update order status but this sends out an email to the customer.  I have hundreds of old customers and i don't want emails to be sent for to them when i update the status.  Is there an alternative way to change the status of an order without sending emails?

Comment: You can go to WooCommerce Settings and disable the completed order email. Then when you mark the orders the email will not send.

Answer (score 14):

WooCommerce by default provides an option to disable complete orders email notification. Here is where you can find the setting.

**Configuring WooCommerce to disable Email notification**

[image]

If this is not what you want and if you want to auto complete orders after it placed you can use the [WooCommerce Autocomplete Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/) or you can just code it your self by adding this code at the end of your functions.php file, which is located in “wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/:” :

/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

Let me know if this solution fits your requirements

Comment: I know you supplied this answer last year, but would have have any idea why Unchecking this field would not stick. I uncheck this box and press save, but refreshing the page shows that it is checked again. I am trying to do a few modifications without notifying clients.

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin maybe? If yes, try to disable it or delete cache and try again..  Do you get a confirmed successfully message ? or any errors to console log;